# Xamarin studio professional edition for mac

Tags: xamarin

how to get Xamarin Studio profession edition for mac machine?

When i try on xamarin website then link redirect me to visual studio windows edition.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.xamarin.com/download-it#download The version (community, Business or Enterprise) is depending on your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The following information comes from the Xamarin FAQ.

**[How do I get the Enterprise features in Visual Studio in Xamarin Studio?](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq8)**

> Xamarin Studio will follow the Visual Studio pricing rules. There is Xamarin Studio Community Edition available for download on the Mac. You’ll need to be a Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber to unlock Visual Studio Enterprise features in Xamarin Studio.

**[I have an MSDN subscription. How do I use Xamarin Studio on my Mac?](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#qp3)**

> Visual Studio Professional and Enterprise subscribers now have access to Professional and Enterprise editions of Xamarin Studio on the Mac included as part of their Visual Studio subscription. Most Visual Studio subscribers should log in to the Visual Studio subscriber portal (or, if you are a Visual Studio cloud subscriber, log into my.visualstudio.com) to access Xamarin Studio (for OS X).

So to conclude, you will need to be a Visual Studio subscriber (what used to be an MSDN subscription) in order to use any Xamarin Studio version other than the Community version.

Furthermore: see [the licensing options](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/license/):

[image: Licensing options]